# Unique nearest point in epsilon neighborhood of compact real manifold?

Tags: manifolds, examples-counterexamples, compactness

I have to proof the following assertion:

Let $X$ be a compact submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathcal{U}^\varepsilon=\{p\in\mathbb{R}^n\;:\; |p-q|<\varepsilon \text{ for some }q\in X\}$. Then there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that every point $p\in\mathcal{U}^\varepsilon$ has a unique nearest point $\pi(x)\in X$.

But is this true at all?

Consider $f(x)=x\cdot\sin(1/x)$ for $x\ne0$ and $f(0)=0$. Since $f$ is continuous, $X=\{(x,f(x)\;|\;x\in[0,1]\}$ is a compact submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $x_1 > x_2 > \ldots$ be all roots of $f$ in $(0,1]$. For every point $\big(\frac{x_{i+1}+x_i}{2},0\big)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ both $(x_i,0)$ and $(x_{i+1},0)$ are nearest points in $X$. And since $x_{i+1}-x_i$ tends to zero, we have such points in every $\mathcal{U}^\varepsilon$.

What is wrong with my argument?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure that For every point (xi+1+xi/2,0)∈R2 both (xi,0) and (xi+1,0) are nearest points in X? There maybe a point on graph   between points xi and xi+1 of function which is nearer to (xi+1+xi/2,0)

Comment: Maybe you are right. But from looking at the graph you see that there is still a point in every $[x_{i+1},x_i]\times\mathbb{R}$ that has two nearest points in $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your homework problem is about *smooth* submanifolds.

Comment: I think you are right, although it was never said explicitly.

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to make use of the fact that $X$ is a smooth submanifold for proving the assertion?

Comment: Hard to do that without knowing what you know from class at this point. I assume you know about tangent and normal bundles for submanifolds of $\mathbb R^n$? Do you know any fancy theorems? If not, a good start would be a proof by contradiction, arriving at some sequences.

Comment: By the way, smoothness prevents the phenomenon you were basing your counterexample on: Curvature would have to be locally bounded everywhere. Large curvature is what makes it possible for a nearby point to have two (or more) closest points.